# Using a jQuery animate callback does not update correctly my Angular model

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

Here is the situation: I have a panel that contains a limited list of elements. I have implemented some sort of slider on it: when I click on a button, this panel moves to the left, and get back with the list of updated items (i.e. the items present on the next page).

My code looks like that:

```
<div id="slider" class="row">
  <span ng-repeat="d in data | startFrom: (page * pagination) | limitTo: pagination" class="col-lg-4 box" >{{ d }}</span>
</div>
<button id="ko" type="button" class="btn btn-danger" ng-click="nextPageAndAnimate();">Next page ({{ page }})</button>
<button id="ok" type="button" class="btn btn-success" ng-click="nextPage();">Next page ({{ page }})</button>
```

on the Angular Controller side:

```
myApp.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {

    $scope.data = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'.split('');
    $scope.page = 0;
    $scope.pagination = 5;

    // Without animation, works correctly.
    $scope.nextPage = function() {
      $scope.page = $scope.page + 1;
    };

    // Use animation, not working correctly.
    $scope.nextPageAndAnimate = function() {
      console.log('Start animation');
      $('#slider').animate({ left: '-200px' }, 1000, function() {
        $scope.page = $scope.page + 1;
        console.log('Page updated');
        $(this).animate({ left: '0' }, 1000, function() {
          console.log('End of animation');
        });
      });
    };

});
```

You have the full example on this [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/sYuMtiaacNb7GmUHongI).

My idea was the following: I start the animation to hide the `#slider`. At the middle of the animation, I update the `$scope.page` model to ask Angular to display the next 5 elements of my list. Finally, I start a new animation to show the `#slider` again.

When using the `button#ok`, I "simply" update the `$scope.page` model value, so the pagination works correctly, but without animation.

If I use the `button#ko`, the update of the `$scope.page` model does not work correctly, but I have animation: on the first click, the box animtes but displays the same elements (i.e. `$scope.page` is still equals to `0`). When I click a second time on the button, *before* the animation, the elements are updated (`$scope.page` is equal to `1`), but at the end, I get the same elements.

I'm not sure to understand why the model is not updated at the correct moment, but I suspect that it's because the update is made in the jQuery `animate` callback, no?
How to solve my problem?

Comment: You can use `++` to increment, i.e. `$scope.page++;` (not a solution though)

Comment: Maybe $scope is not within the scope of the callback function?

Comment: @NigelAngel Yes, using `++` will not make any difference. I think `$scope.page` is available in the callback function, as it is updated at the end. My idea is that the model is updated, but Angular is not aware of that modification because it is not made by him, but by jQuery...

Comment: Have you looked at [`ngAnimate`](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngAnimate/service/$animate) instead? [guide](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/animations)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you called `scope.$apply()` whenever you update the page in the animation? Angular is smart when binding click events to controller functions, automatically checking for scope changes when they have been executed.

In your animation however, the scope update does not happen until a few milliseconds after the click event has been triggered. There is no way for angular to tell that the scope has been updated. This is the reason `scope.$apply()` exists.

See also: [https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/When-to-use-$scope.$apply()](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/When-to-use-%24scope.%24apply%28%29)

Comment: You confirmed my doubt, and that was exactly what I was looking for. Thanks.